# iOS:Setting UICollectionView cell to view size

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, xcode8.2

I'm trying to figure out how to setup the frame of the UICollectionView cell to the frame of the view (similar of how photo app) but I need to do it programmatically. Any of you knows how can I do this?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sizeForItemAt indexPath` method on `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`. This will determine the size of each cell, and can be configured to be relative to the size of other elements (like your `view`, for example).

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width / 2, height: 50)
}
```

Just make sure the `deleagte` of your collection view is set, and the delegate conforms to the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` protocol.